# Typescript integration with complex redux actions and reducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, action, reducers

I'm new to typescript at the moment and I'm trying to combine it to redux actions and reducers. I'm getting an error right now and I want the best approach to refactoring the code. This was my method, and I need assistance.

**Action**

```
import Axios from "axios";

export const fetchTODO = term => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: "FETCH_TODO" });

  try {
    const response = await Axios.get(`/api/TODO/${term}`, {});
    dispatch({
      type: "FETCH_TODO_SUCCESS",
      payload: response.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_TODO_FAILURE", error });
  }
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  payload: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: {}
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload, error }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "FETCH_TODO":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };

    case "FETCH_TODO_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, payload, isLoading: false };

    case "FETCH_TODO_FAILURE":
      return { ...state, error: error, isLoading: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Typescript code**

types.tc

```
export enum ActionTypes {
  fetchTodos,
  fetchTodosSuccess,
  fetchTodosFailure
}
```

**Action**

```
import { ActionTypes } from "./types";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";

export interface Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

export interface FetchTodoAction {
  type: ActionTypes;
  payload?: Todo[];
  error?: object;
}

export const fetchTransaction = (term: string) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch
) => {
  dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.fetchTodos });

  try {
    const response = await Axios.get<Todo[]>(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`
    );
    dispatch<FetchTodoAction>({
      type: ActionTypes.fetchTodosSuccess,
      payload: response.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.fetchTodosFailure, error });
  }
};
```

StateInterface object

```
export interface StateInterface {
  payload?: Todo[];
  isLoading: boolean;
  error?: object;
}
```

**Reducer**

```
import { Todo, FetchTodoAction } from "./../actions/index";
import { ActionTypes } from "../actions/types";
import { StateInterface } from ".";

const initialState = {
  payload: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: {}
};

export const todosReducer = (
  state: StateInterface = initialState,
  { type, payload, error }: FetchTodoAction
) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.fetchTodos:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };

    case ActionTypes.fetchTodosSuccess:
      return { ...state, payload, isLoading: false };

    case ActionTypes.fetchTodosFailure:
      return { ...state, error: error, isLoading: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I got this error after the code and anyone can please tell me the best implementation

```
(alias) const todosReducer: (state: StateInterface | undefined, { type, payload, error }: FetchTodoAction) => StateInterface
import todosReducer
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<StateInterface, any>): Reducer<CombinedState<StateInterface>, AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ todos: (state: StateInterface | undefined, { type, payload, error }: FetchTodoAction) => StateInterface; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject<StateInterface, any>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'todos' does not exist in type 'ReducersMapObject<StateInterface, any>'.
```

**please, I'm really looking forward to some support, and thank you in advance**

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown because TypeScript prevents you from having an argument to be option (i.e. `undefined`) when following arguments are required (i.e. not `undefined`).

You can fix this by inferring the type from the `initialState`.

Eg. `const initialState: StateInterface { ... }`

Now you no longer have to set the type for state in your reducer arguments, since TypeScript will know that this value will always be defined.

Eg. `export const todosReducer = (state = initialState, ...) => { ... }`

Therefore, change your reducer code to the following:

```
import { Todo, FetchTodoAction } from "./../actions/index";
import { ActionTypes } from "../actions/types";
import { StateInterface } from ".";

// Define initial state type here
const initialState: StateInterface = {
  payload: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: {}
};

export const todosReducer = (
  state = initialState, // state type is now inferred from initialState
  { type, payload, error }: FetchTodoAction
) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.fetchTodos:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };

    case ActionTypes.fetchTodosSuccess:
      return { ...state, payload, isLoading: false };

    case ActionTypes.fetchTodosFailure:
      return { ...state, error, isLoading: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**EDIT:**
If this still doesn't work then changing `{ type, payload, error }: FetchTodoAction` to `{ type, payload, error }: FetchTodoAction | undefined` should do the trick.